# Выводит иероглифы вместо русских букв

Tags: php

Почему не выводит русские символы?

[image: Скриншот]

в корень с файлом создал файл .htaccess и записал в него AddDefaultCharset utf-8 
и всё равно не помогает.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Массивы</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    ///////длина строки

    echo "длина строки - 'Hello, world': " . strlen('Hello, world').' символов<br>';


    /////////функция, которая считает повторение символов в строке

    $data = 'g dgdthrdhd ewtewj ';
    $result = count_chars($data, 0);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++){
        if($result[$i] !=0){
            echo chr($i). ' встречается в строке ' . $result[$i] . ' раз <br>';
        }
    }

    ////////////реверс строки

    echo strrev('компьютер');


?>
```

Answer (score 3):

`strrev` не поддерживает utf-8, как и многие другие функции в php. в документации первым [комментарием](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strrev.php#62422) предлагают вот такое решение

```
function utf8_strrev($str){
    preg_match_all('/./us', $str, $ar);
    return join('',array_reverse($ar[0]));
}
```